# Confusion about site enabling/disabling

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04

Very new to setting up a web server. I am confused by something. First of all this is `apache2` on `ubuntu 18.04`. I literally have no `conf` files in my `sites-enabled` folder. I am confused as to how my site still comes up? My `apache2.conf` file has this at the bottom of the file:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Now the fact that is says `IncludeOption` leads me to believe that there is some default configuration that gets loaded. This is what I am not sure about.

Again, apologies for such a simple question, but as I said, very new to this.

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Sites-enabled is for virtual hosts.

Apache2 is capable of getting requests for different domains. Ie.. site1.com, site2.com...

And then responding with html or other files from seperate directory folders.

A change to the host file and a file added in sites-enabled is one way of hosting multiple sites.